# Fill rectangle in the picture with text

Tags: php, image, algorithm, text, imagemagick

I have got a picture with fixed size and variable number of text (User can define what to show and what do not). Now I want to fill rectangle in the picture with selected text. Simpliest solution would be using fixed coordinates for every text. But as I said before, user can select what to show. I do not want to show "free spaces" just because user do not want to show the text which should be at this place.

I have found this [page](http://valokuva.org/?p=93). The author described exactly what I need. Problem is I do not have Imagick php class on my webserver.

Could you please provide me another function or algorithm for this problem?
Thank you
lorin

Comment: The basic algorithm for horizontally centering the text is `$xCoord = ($widthOfRectangle - $widthOfText) / 2;`. You can get the width of a text character with [`imagefontwidth()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefontwidth.php), the number of characters can be obtained with `strlen()` and you presumably already know the width of the rectangle. The same logic applies to the Y axis, just use the heights instead.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I knew that. My problem is that I use more than one text. In fact I have got three columns. And every column contains X rows. In this case I want to set the font size dynamically based on the rectangle size and text length/height.